# Ruby Watir: Checkbox not begin recognized as set

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, watir

Using watir-classic 3.6.0 on IE10.

I'm having difficulty getting my page to recognize when I set a checkbox.

I've tried:

```
b.checkbox(:id => myId).set
b.checkbox(:id => myId).click
b.checkbox(:id => myId).fire_event('onclick')
```

For all of those, I can see that my checkbox is checked.  Also, puts b.checkbox.set? return true.

However, I then click a button that requires at least one checkbox to be set in order to function, and it tells me that no checkboxes are set.

This is the html for the checkbox:
[image: htmlOfCheckbox]

What would cause the browser/webpage to not recognize a checkbox as being set when it is visibly checked?

Comment: Can you share the code please ?

Comment: All it is is: $browser.checkbox(:id => "allBox").when_present.set followed by $browser.button(:value => "Select").click. I've tried the variants in my original post to replace the first line.  All of them check the box, but the Select button throws an error saying nothing is checked.

Comment: Is there any client-side logic that is supposed to occur when checking the checkbox? For example, I had one application where setting the checkboxes actually populated a hidden field. Perhaps your application is doing similar and for some reason the event to populate that hidden field is not firing.

Comment: Justin: WOuld that be visible in the HTML?  There doesn't appear to be any javascript firing on the checkbox.

Comment: With web pages these days I do not believe it has to be right in the element's html (but I am not a web developer). Does the all checkbox cause other chechboxes to get checked (when done manually)?

Comment: No.  Checking the boxes doesn't affect any other boxes.